# Adding Loading Screens to multiple UIWebViews

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Im building an app with multiple `uiwebviews`. I wanted to add loading screens to make the app easier to use. I've added one for one of my webviews using this code.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)vieWeb
{
_loadingmain.hidden=NO;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)viewWeb
{
_loadingmain.hidden=YES;
}
```

viewWeb is the name of one of my uiwebviews. How would I add a load scree for my other two webviews? adding identical code with a different name for the webview causes the error `"duplicate declaration of method webViewDidFinishLoad"`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have multiple UIWebViews on one page, right? If so, you have a few options:

1) Create a subclass of UIWebView and set itself as the web view delegate, that way each UIWebView subclass handles it's own loading view.

2) You could also create multiple instances of your loading views and do something like

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if( webView == self.webView1 )
    {
        [self.webView1 addSubview:self.loadingView1];
    }
    else if( webView == self.webView2 )
    {
        [self.webView2 addSubview:self.loadingView2];
    }
    //repeat for other webviews
}   

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if( webView == self.webView1 )
    {
        [self.loadingView1 removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else if( webView == self.webView2 )
    {
        [self.loadingView2 removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //repeat for other webviews
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I keep getting a warning next to every webview = self.webview... saying either use double parentheses or double equals sign. Which should I do and why?

Comment: Do I need to declare the loading view's delegates as self? If that even makes any sense... And how if thats necessary. I tried <UIImageViewDelegate> in my header but that got an error.

Comment: sorry, should be ==, will fix the example.

Comment: UIWebViewDelegate bro.

Comment: Now im getting white webviews :(